# how can I access my store from RTK-Query endpoints?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to access to my redux-toolkit store data inside of the `rtk-query` endpoints.

how can I access my store from `query` or `transformResponse` methods?

```
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import customFetchBase from './customFetchBase.js'
import { setUserInfo, setUserPermissions } from '../features/userSlice.js'
import { aesDEC } from 'src/util/public.util.js'

export const authApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'authApi',
  baseQuery: customFetchBase,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getUser: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
        url: '/Account/Login/GetUserInfo',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
          RequestVerificationToken: salt //here I want the salt from my redux store
        }
      }),
      transformResponse: response => {
        return aesDEC(response.data, salt); //here I want the salt from my redux store
      },
    }),
})
export const { useGetUserMutation } = authApi
```

Comment: Replace `query` with a `queryFn` which will provide `api.getState` and also remove `transformResponse`.  With `queryFn` you will do the work of both your `query` and your `transformResponse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `query` nor `transformResponse` have direct access to the Redux state, however, you can replace both with the [`queryFn`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#queryfn) which does. With `queryFn` the query function used is passed the query `arg`, the base query `api` object, any defined `extraOptions`, and the `baseQuery` function. Use `api.getState` to access the current state value.

Example, your code might look similar to the following:

```
export const authApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'authApi',
  baseQuery: customFetchBase,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getUser: builder.mutation({
      queryFn: async (arg, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        const state = api.getState();
        const salt = state./* path to salt state value */;

        try {
          const { data } = await = baseQuery({
            url: '/Account/Login/GetUserInfo',
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
              RequestVerificationToken: salt
            }
          });
          return { data: aesDEC(data, salt) };
        } catch(error) {
          return { error };
        }
      },
    }),
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get access to the state in fetchBaseQuery/prepareHeaders function like this if you need to set Auth or some general header:

```
export const DataApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
    baseUrl: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`, 
    prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState}) => {
      const state = getState();
      headers.set(HEADER_AUTH, state?.auth?.value?.authorization);
    }
  }),
 ...
});
```